# apache tomcat connector - website configuration

Tags: apache, tomcat, connector, mod-jk, ajp

I have deployed website serving traffic from apache which get pages from tomcat. i have configured mod_jk connector and everything is working fine.

say for example my website url is   `http://<mywebsite.com>`
my tomcat deployed application app name  test app

Problem is im only able to browse the site when i browse `http://<mywebsite.com>/testapp` but i want apache to serve pages when i browse just my website `http://<mywebsite.com>` and it is not happening at the moment. below is my apache httpd.conf file and testapp is my deployed application name on tomcat.

```
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogStampFormat "[%b %d %Y - %H:%M:%S] "
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
JkLogLevel info

JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

Alias /testapp "C:/Items/Installation Directories/Tomcat7.0/webapps/awardio/"

<Directory "C:/Items/Installation Directories/Tomcat7.0/webapps/awardio/">
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location /*/WEB-INF/*>
    deny from all
</Location>

JkMount /testapp/* myworker
```

do i need to mod_rewrite or something or configure virtual host.

it is fairly urgent so appreciate your help?

Answer (score 0):

```
my tomcat deployed application app name test app
```

You need to change the deployed app name to `ROOT`. So you can just rename the war file to `ROOT.war`